# Swift: Validate Username Input

Tags: ios, regex, swift

Working on a Swift app and I have a form filled by user and I would like the user to select their own username. The only constraints I want on the username are:

> - No special characters (e.g. @,#,$,%,&,*,(,),^,<,>,!,±)
> - Only letters, underscores and numbers allowed
> - Length should be 18 characters max and 7 characters minimum

Where can I find a function that validates an input string (function parameter) and return true or false based on above criteria? I am not very well versed in regular expressions.

Comment: You should post what you tried.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may use

```
^\w{7,18}$
```

or

```
\A\w{7,18}\z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xH3xX2/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of the string (can be replaced with `\A` to ensure start of string only matches)
- `\w{7,18}` - 7 to 18 word characters (i.e. any *Unicode* letters, digits or underscores, if you only allow ASCII letters and digits, use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead)
- `$` - end of string (for validation, I'd rather use `\z` instead to ensure end of string only matches).

**Swift code**

Note that if you use it with `NSPredicate` and `MATCHES`, you do not need the start/end of string anchors, as the match will be anchored by default:

```
func isValidInput(Input:String) -> Bool {
    let RegEx = "\\w{7,18}"
    let Test = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", RegEx)
    return Test.evaluateWithObject(Input)
}
```

Else, you should not omit the anchors:

```
func isValidInput(Input:String) -> Bool {
    return Input.range(of: "\\A\\w{7,18}\\z", options: .regularExpression) != nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support...The explanation is really helpful...allows me to modify for future scenarios

Comment: why is it necessary to specify start of the string and end of the string?

Comment: @andrei You do not have to use `\A` and `\z` in case you are using the regex with `MATCHES` in the `NSPredicate` as it anchors the regex pattern by default. However, it is a good idea to keep the anchors explicit in the pattern in case you want to test it in any online regex testers, or just to have a better feel of what the regex does. Also, if you use it in other methods that do not anchor the pattern by default, its behavior won't change.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, it is necessary when trying a regex with an online tool, as it matches regexes only between the anchors. I might have a longer string, but regex matching will only apply to the part of it that's between the anchors. Is that correct?

Comment: @andrei I suggest you read [*Anchors* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html). `^` or `\A` will match the start of the string, and `$` or `\z` will match the end of the string, and if you place anything before `^` or after `$`, the pattern will never match as there are no chars before the start of the string and there are no chars after its end.

Answer (score 8):

```
func validateUsername(str: String) -> Bool
{
    do
    {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9a-zA-Z\\_]{7,18}$", options: .CaseInsensitive)
        if regex.matchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count)).count > 0 {return true}
    }
    catch {}
    return false
}
```

Comment: Found this easier to edit and use for name validation too. Thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4

```
extension String {

    var isValidName: Bool {
       let RegEx = "^\\w{7,18}$"
       let Test = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", RegEx)
       return Test.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func isValidUsername(testStr:String) -> Bool {

        var rawString: String = testStr
        var whitespace: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
        trimmed = rawString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(whitespace)

        if trimmed.characters.count>0
        {

            return true
        }
        else
        {

            return false
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are powerful, but here is pure Swift solution.
Exact answer to your question:

```
func isValidUsername(_ name: String, forbiddenChars: String = "@#$%&*()^<>!±", lengthRange: Range<Int> = 3..<19) -> Bool {
    guard  lengthRange ~= name.count , name.first!.isLetter else { return false }
    return name.allSatisfy{ !forbiddenChars.contains($0) }
}

isValidUsername("tom3")    // true
isValidUsername("tom_c")   // false (note disallowed underscope)
isValidUsername("3tom")    // false
isValidUsername("tom#$%&") // false
```

A common thing to want is to have only alphanumerics in a user name:

```
func alphanumericsOnly(_ name: String, lengthRange: Range<Int> = 3..<19) -> Bool {
    guard  lengthRange ~= name.count , name.first!.isLetter else { return false }
    return name.allSatisfy{ $0.isLetter || $0.isNumber }
}
```

Important thing to note here is that some emoji's and all diacritics count as alphanumerics which may be not what you want.

```
alphanumericsOnly("tom3️⃣")     // true
alphanumericsOnly("Ḡ͓̟̟r̬e̱̬͔͑g̰ͮ̃͛T̆a̐̑͢ṫ̀ǔ̓͟m̮̩̠̟") // true
alphanumericsOnly("tom_")      // false
```

So the most strict way for latin username can be checked as follows:

```
func asciiOnly<R: RangeExpression>(_ name: String, lengthRange: R) -> Bool where R.Bound == Int {
    guard  lengthRange ~= name.count , name.first!.isLetter else { return false }
    return name.allSatisfy{ $0.isASCII }
}

asciiOnly("tom_c", lengthRange: 3...)   // true (infinite length)
asciiOnly("tom3️⃣", lengthRange: 3...18) // false
asciiOnly("tomё", lengthRange: 3..<19)  // false
```