# How To Restrict A Username Textfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield

In my project user's can type out the username they want. I will like to restrict this field where they can only use letters, numbers and a underscore (like Instagram). I've searched the internet for hours but can not come up with anything. How can I do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938435/swift-validate-username-input) question which fully describes it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      let s = NSString(string: textField.text ?? "").replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
      guard !s.isEmpty else { return true }
      let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
      numberFormatter.numberStyle = .none
      return numberFormatter.number(from: s)?.intValue != nil
 }
```